# Unhandled exception in page_load Event

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, pageload

There is an unhandled exception in `Page_Load` event , where can we handle these errors

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of hooks for error handling in asp.net.

There are `Page_Error` and also `Application_Error` events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w16865z6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about just adding a try/catch statement to your page_load code?